# if-else statement and code exit

Tags: python, if-statement

basically I'm quite new to python so I decided to make a simple calculator, I have done the coding for the calculator and that all works and I am happy, however I would like an if-else statement to see if they would like to continue with another calculation. So this is the top part of my code and the bottom part of my code, I would like to know how to get it so that after the 'else' part of the code, it just runs the rest of the code.

```
import os
done = ("")
if done == True:
    os._exit(0)
else:
    print ("---CALCULATOR---")

...

done = str(input("Would you like to do another calculation? (Y/N) "))
if done == "N" or "n":
    done = True
if done == "Y" or "y":
    done = False
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a `while` loop. Continue performing calculations until the user says `'N'`.

Comment: In addition to @keikoku's answer, you don't need to check `if done == "Y" or "y"` since you have initialized `done = False`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want something like this...

```
import os
done = False

while not done:
    print ("---CALCULATOR---")
    ...

    # be careful with the following lines, they won't actually do what you expect
    done = str(input("Would you like to do another calculation? (Y/N) "))
    if done == "N" or "n":
        done = True
    if done == "Y" or "y":
        done = False
```

Comment: `done == 'N' or 'n'` is always true, as is `done == 'Y' or 'y'`.

Comment: Use casefold() like this: done.casefold() == 'n'. Then, you will not need to worry about case sensitivity. This allows you do include the word 'no' without typing it every different way.

Answer (score 2):

`if done == "N" or "n":`

The above condition checks whether `done == "N"` or `"n"`. This will always evaluate to `True` because in Python, a non-empty string evaluates to boolean `True`.

As suggested in the comments you should use a while loop to have the program continue to execute until the user types in "N" or "n".

```
import os
finished = False

while not finished:
    print ("---CALCULATOR---")
    ...

    done = str(input("Would you like to do another calculation? (Y/N) "))
    if done == "N" or done == "n":
        finished = True
```

Comment: or simply `if done in 'Nn'`. Or to take care of empty inputs `done in ('N', 'n')`.