# I'm trying to create a signup and login system in python for some homework. It's not working as intended though

Tags: python

```
    ExistingUser = input("Please enter either Y or N: ")

if (ExistingUser) == "N" or "n":
    newName = input("Please enter your name: ")
    with open("Userdata.txt", "a") as f:
        print(newName, file = f)
    newUserID = input("Please enter your desired username: ")
    with open("Userdata.txt", "a") as f:
        print(newUserID, file = f)
    newPassword = input("Please enter your desired password: ")
    with open("Userdata.txt", "a") as f:
        print(newPassword, file = f)
        f.close()

elif (ExistingUser) == "Y" or "y":
    existingUserID = input("Please enter your username: ")
    with open("Userdata.txt") as f:
        if (ExistingUserID) in f.read():
            print("True")
```

When I type in Y or y, it should trigger the login process. Instead, however it triggers the signup one.

Comment: `(ExistingUser) == "N" or "n"` == `((ExistingUser) == "N") or ("n")` Use `ExistingUser.lower() == "n"`, or `(ExistingUser) in ["N", "n"]`, or `(ExistingUser) == "N" or (ExistingUser) ==  "n"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if-else statement and code exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961400/if-else-statement-and-code-exit)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

`if (ExistingUser) == "N" or "n":` is same as `if (ExistingUser) == "N" or True:` so your if condition is always `True`
For more info - read [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

use `if ExistingUser in ('N', 'n'):`

or `if ExistingUser.lower() == 'n':`

Note that there is no need to use brackets around `ExistingUser`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your If statements are not correct It seems to work if you you change them to this format

if (ExistingUser == "N" or ExistingUser == "n"):

elif (ExistingUser == "Y" or ExistingUser ==  "y"):

In this format:
if (ExistingUser) == "N" or "n":

the 'or "n"' evaluates to true all the time